# Merge dataframes in Pyspark with same column names

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Is there any substitute to suffixes when using pyspark joins?
or
when using `spark.sql(query)`

The data frames have same columns and I want to keep both of them with their respective dataFrame name as suffixes.

Below code is how I did in python.

```
df = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2, on= 'col1', how= 'inner', suffixes= ('_df1', '__df2'))
df = pd.merge(left = df, right = df3, on= 'vin_17', how= 'inner', suffixes= ('','__df3'))
df = pd.merge(left = df, right = df4, on= 'vin_17', how= 'inner', suffixes= ('','__df4'))
```

This is how I did in pyspark, but then all column names are changing and I want duplicated columns to have `__suffix` only.

```
df1 = df1.select(*(col(x).alias(x + '__df1') for x in df1.columns))
df2 = df2.select(*(col(x).alias(x + '__df2') for x in df2.columns))
df3 = df3.select(*(col(x).alias(x + '__df3') for x in df3.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter only the common columns betwwen the 3 dataframes when renaming :

```
def get_common_cols(dfs: list):
    seen = set()
    repeated = set()
    for l in [df.columns for df in dfs]:
        for i in set(l):
            if i in seen:
                repeated.add(i)
            else:
                seen.add(i)

    return list(repeated)

common = get_common_cols([df1, df2, df3])

# rename only if x exists in common_cols
df1 = df1.select(*[col(x).alias(f"{x}__df1" if x in common else x) for x in df1.columns])
df2 = df2.select(*[col(x).alias(f"{x}__df2" if x in common else x) for x in df2.columns])
df3 = df3.select(*[col(x).alias(f"{x}__df3" if x in common else x) for x in df3.columns])
```

Comment: the common line returns a null list ,

Comment: list(set.intersection(*[set(cols) for cols in all_cols]))

Comment: @user12063090 what do you mean by null list? Empty ?

Comment: yes, an empty set. and I tried with another temporary list, p= [[ 'name1', 'name2'], ['name3', 'name1']] 
list(set.intersection(*[set(cols) for cols in p])) 
also returns empty set

Comment: p= [[ 'name1', 'name2'], ['name1', 'name3']]

if name 1 is on first location, only then it returns name1 , but thats not the case in my dataFrame, columns are not in same location, some are in last, some is in first location

Comment: @user12063090 Hemm it returns `['name1']` in both cases for me. what is your python version?

Comment: i'm using pyspark

Comment: is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: @user12063090 please see my update. I changed the way to find the common cols between the df